# How can I see deployed Application in Apache Tomee

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, activemq-classic, apache-tomee

Today I started to use `Apache Tomee` for my web Application(Servlet,jsp,Activemq).Previously I tested with `Tomcat 7` in `Eclipse` it's working fine.I exported `War` file from `Eclipse`.

I open `Tomee` web console page and deployed my WAR file from console.it's showing message as `Sucessfully deployed`.

But I can't able to see my Application in `ListOfApplications` category.

These same WAR file I tried in `Tomcat`,there everything fine.

**Why I am interesting on Tomee** : `Activemq` comes inbuilt with `Tomee` so I want to use `Tomee`.

can anyone help me.

Where will I see my deployed Application in `Tomee` also suggest me How can I check whether `Tomee` comes with `Activemq` or not.If `AMQ` is inbuilt how can I open that corresponding console page because I want to see How many consumers are running .

Thanks.